# How can I use the secure strcpy_s function?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to update a call to `strcpy` with the more secure `strcpy_s`. The old function call looks like this:

```
char buf[6];
strcpy(buf+1, "%#c");
```

In order to turn the above code into the more secure version, what would I put in for the size parameter?

```
char buf[6];
strcpy_s(buf+1, /*SIZE GOES HERE*/, "%#c");
```

I suppose I am getting confused with the `buf+1` portion of the code. Is that essentially just a pointer that points to the register ONE block over from `buf`? If so, what would I put in for the SIZE parameter of `strcpy_s`? I have tried:

```
  strcpy_s(buf+1, sizeof(buf+1), "%#c");
```

which seems to work, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You can't point to a register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were copying into the *start* of `buf`, you'd say:

```
strcpy_s(buf, sizeof(buf), "%#c");
```

since you're skipping the first character, you have one *less* character to work with, so:

```
strcpy_s(buf + 1, sizeof(buf) - 1, "%#c");
```

Answer (score 1):

The size should be `5` (assuming you want to skip the first index). A proper way to calculate is:

```
int offset = 1; // not necessary, but shows the connection between the size and offset
strcpy_s(buf+offset, (sizeof(buf)-offset) / sizeof(buf[0]), "%#c");
```

Division by char size is redundant, but it's good to remember because it's necessary if you use a wide characters.

Comment: +1: You should instead use the object itself: `... sizeof buf / sizeof *buf ...`

Comment: -1 for using `sizeof(buf[0])` with a character `buf` (remember: `sizeof (char)` is 1) and subtracting `offset` *without* scaling. That's just weird.

Comment: @unwind, I've fixed the scaling. If the code is changed to use a wide character, then it would fail without scaling. That would make the code more rigid. It's a matter of taste, in my opinion.

Comment: @user2079303 You can't use `strcpy_s()` with wide characters, you have to use [`wstrcpy_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) since there's a big risk of wide charactrs having 0-bytes, which would of course fool `strcpy_s()` into thinking it has the hit end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`buf+1` points to the memory location one past the starting address of `buf`, so effectively the copy starts from that location. But the `size` parameter specifies the *size of the destination*. It does not make sense to use `sizeof(buf+1)` for that parameter. You should pass the available space of the destination ( *should be <= (total size - starting offset)*).

In your case, it should be

```
strcpy_s(buf+1, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf) - 1, "%#c");
```

[look here for details](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/118771/)

Comment: `strcpy_s()` wants the size of the destination, not the number of elements to copy. Two very different things.